# Class Self-Reference Issues

Tags: c++, class, self-reference

All of my code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/GRrdap0b).

I'm trying to create a complicated tree ***for a project*** however this is just the beginning of the project (the construction of a data structure). Also, I think it would help to know that the data structure can be anything you want, and that I really want to do it this way. If you think another is better, that's grand, but I don't want to change my data structure if I don't have to, as I'd like to follow this idea through.

That said, I'm creating a tree.

Each node of the tree contains a string of content, bool of if it is a non-terminal (if it has children or if it is a leaf).

Additionally, each node contains a pointer to a vector (let's call that vector v).

V is such that it contains other vectors. Let's call one of those vectors X.

X contains a pointer to a node.

The code works fine except for when X contains a pointer to the node which contains V (if that makes sense). When X contains a pointer to the node which contains V, I get an infinite loop which terminates in a seg fault.

I've been hashing this out for an hour and am pretty sure the problem is in my deconstructor, which looks like this:

```
Node :: ~Node () {
    for (int i = 0; i < (*children).size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (*children)[i].size(); j++) {
            if ((*children)[i][j] != selfP) {
                delete (*children)[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (*children).size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < (*children)[i].size(); j++) {
        if ((*children)[i][j] != CURRENT_NODE_ADDRESS) {
            delete (*children)[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't quite figure out how to reference the address of a class I'm currently defining. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried the [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_(computer_programming))(link) pointer?

Comment: Wouldn't `this` be the address of children? Or would it be of the node?

Comment: `children` is populated through `addLeaves` in Node.cpp (see pastebin at top of question).

Comment: @nicko if you put that as an answer I can resolve this question, thank you.

Comment: If you have cycles then it is **not** a tree. It is a graph. But code is worth a million words in English.

Comment: @LokiAstari, thanks for the information, I'm still learning. What do you mean by cycles? Is what rules it out of being a tree that a Node can point to itself or another Node's child?

Comment: @JamesRoseman: Just as real trees don't have branches that reconnect, a tree _structure_ can't reconnect (can't have itself as a child).  A generic graph _can_ have arbitrary connections though.  (trees are a subset of graphs, like apples are a subset of fruits)

Comment: @JamesRoseman "this" would point to the current node from looking at your pastebin.

Comment: So does this [image](http://imgur.com/FSUdT) represent a graph or a tree? Sorry if it's upside down, there should only be one root node at the top of the photo.

Comment: @James: if it has nodes and lines connecting them, it's a graph.  If all teh arrows point "down", then it's a tree-graph.  Some of your arrows point up, ergo, it is a graph, but not a tree-graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried the [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_%28computer_programming%29) pointer?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can easily compare your object with 'this' :

```
if (children[i][j] == this)
{
...
}
```

where children[i][j] is a pointer to an instance of the class that you are writing deconstructor.

Comment: Thanks Nasser, but nicko got here first! That is the right answer though, it works like a charm.